# Get Account User Id FBML

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'm new to the facebook app making and I'm just wondering how I can get the user who enabled the app (the one using it)'s user id.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook('API', 'SECRET');
echo $facebook->user;
```

Answer (score 0):

The new PHP SDK is available here: http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk. It has an example that shows how to get the user id and profile: http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php.